# Como capturar un file al entrar a una pagina angular y guardarlo en una propiedad

Tags: angular

esperen esten bien, estoy haciendo el una aplicacion y con un pequeño catalogo, algo improvisado, lo que trato de hacer es que cuando le de click al producto, este me lleve a un formulario y me imprima todo, esto funciona perfectamente, en la consola puedo ver el objeto con todas las propiedades del objeto, lo cual me permite actualizar el producto SOLO si cambio otra vez la imagen que trae consigo, tengo una funcion que detecta cuando subo una imagen y la asigna al file, lo que quiero saber si es posible que al momento de cargar la pagina esta guarde ya de por si esa imagen que trae del producto y la almacene en ese file.

Este es mi ngOnInit, al momento de pedir el file por consola me viene como undefined

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.id = params['id'];
      this.productService.getProduct(this.id).subscribe(
        (res) => {
          console.log(res);
          this.product = res;
          this.updateProductForm.controls['description'].setValue(
            res.description
          );
          this.updateProductForm.controls['name'].setValue(res.name);
          this.updateProductForm.controls['price'].setValue(res.price);
          console.log(this.file);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

Solo me actualiza si cambio de nuevo la imagen, quisiera que si no se cambiara, esta imagen mantuviese el file con el que se guardó.

```
onPhotoSelected(event: HtmlInputEvent): void {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files) {
      this.file = <File>event.target.files[0];
      //Image Preview
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = (e) => (this.photoSelected = reader.result);
      reader.readAsDataURL(this.file);
    }
  }

  updateProduct(id: String) {
    this.productService
      .updateProduct(id, this.updateProductForm.value, this.file)
      .subscribe(
        (res) => {
          this.resetForm(this.updateProductForm);
          Swal.fire({
            title: 'Actualizacion exitosa!',
            text: 'Juego actualizado correctamente',
            icon: 'success',
            confirmButtonColor: '#6c5ce7',
          });
          this.router.navigate(['/home']);
        },
        (err) => {
          console.log(err);
          Swal.fire({
            icon: 'error',
            title: 'Algo salio mal',
            text: 'No pudimos agregar el juego',
            confirmButtonColor: '#6c5ce7',
          });
        }
      );
  }
```

**Soy novato en angular**

Comment: Tendrás que almacenar físicamente ese fichero en el servidor y guardar en algún sitio la referencia o la ruta a ese fichero (base de datos, un JSON, ...). Cuando se cargue la página del producto, ver si el producto tiene asociado una imagen y si la tiene, cargarla de donde esté almacenada.

Comment: @VRoxa Hola, creo que eso es lo que hago, al guardar un producto, se guarda la imagen física en una carpeta, luego para mostrarla al entrar al card que es la pagina donde voy a editar, lo que hago es esto `<img
              [src]="
                photoSelected ||
                'http://localhost:3000/public/' + product.imageName
              "
              class="img-fluid img-card-top"
              (click)="photoInput.click()"
            />` Y pues solo la pinta en pantalla, no queda asignado a algo, por eso al tratar de actualizar no puedo hacerlo, por que el File va vacío